# Can I prevent implicit conversion of an int typedef to int?

Tags: c++, casting

I'd like the following to not compile.

```
typedef int relative_index_t;  // Define an int to only use for indexing.
void function1(relative_index_t i) {
  // Do stuff.
}

relative_index_t y = 1; function1(y);  // I want this to build.
int x = 1; function1(x);               // I want this to NOT build!
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no implicit conversion. `relative_index_t` and `int` are the exact same type. If you want them to be different types, define a class.

Comment: A `typedef` is just an alias not a unique type: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200025/declare-types-without-implicit-conversion-in-c      will give some more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that with `typedef`.

Use following instead:

```
enum class relative_index_t : int {};
```

Example usage:

```
int a = 0;
relative_index_t b;
b = (relative_index_t)a; // this doesn't compile without a cast
a = (int)b; // this too
```

Or following if you prefer C++-style casts:

```
int a = 0;
relative_index_t b;
b = static_cast<relative_index_t>(a);
a = static_cast<int>(b);
```

---

Also you can use [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp).
<sup>[(Credits to @AlexanderPoluektov)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200076/2752075)</sup>

Comment: I'd suggest using `static_cast` in your examples. Parenthetical casts in C++ should be avoided.

Comment: @cdhowie I'd say one may use C-style casts in simple expressions. But that's a good point, edited.

Answer (score 0):

One technique borrow's from Modula-2's opaque types:

```
typedef struct {
              int  index;
        } relative_index_t;
```

That's probably good enough for preventing conversion with `int`.  It also allows another member variable to allow additional features like age, sequence number generation, bounds checking, etc.