# Is there a good way to force type incompatibility in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, typechecking

For purposes of type checking I would like to define a function on the lines of

```
void myfunc(type1 a, type2 b)
{
...
}
```

where `type1` and `type2` are both typedefed to `uint8_t`.  So far so good, but for sanity and checking purposes (think DbC) I would like to prevent the function being called with a `type2` value for the first parameter or a `type1` for the second.  Sadly, C's implicit typecasting is against me here.  Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: That's not C's implicit typecasting against you. You would have the same problem in C++. By definition, using a typedef is the same as using the typedef'ed type.

Comment: You may also take a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs

Comment: Also being discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108046/preventing-automatic-casts-with-integers (for C++ but they will share some ideas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap the two types in a Struct.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t data;
} type1;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t data;
} type2;
```

Edit:
I don't like it because you now have to use a.data instead of a

Comment: why do you say it is not nice ? The intention is clear: the types are different.

Comment: Yes, this is right.  Despite the name, `typedef` doesn't actually introduce a new type in C - only `struct` and `union` do that.

Comment: I agree that having to use a.data is slightly inconvenient, other than that it seems quite clean to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, read that last comment as "although it is slightly inconvenient, it still seems quite a clean solution".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap your types using struct and then pass pointer to these structs.

Comment: You can even pass the structs itself instead of pointers. Structs don't have to be passed by ref, they can be passed by value (in that case the whole struct content is copied; so not a good idea for big structs). Passing them by value has no overhead, if the struct itself is not bigger than a pointer reference would be in size.