# Strong typedef static checker (unix)

Tags: c, typedef, typechecking

Is there a **free** tool (some kind of a static checker) that does typedef-based type-checking for a **plain** C (not C++) and runs on Linux (or any kind of free Unix)? I am aware of a commercial one: PC-lint/FlexeLint. It does exactly what I want, but it's not free and Windows-only. Here is an example from it's manual:

```
typedef int Count;
typedef int Bool;
Count n;
Bool stop;
.
.
.
n = stop ; // tool generates a warning here
```

I've already read this [Enforce strong type checking in C (type strictness for typedefs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs) and this [Is there a good way to force type incompatibility in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140035/is-there-a-good-way-to-force-type-incompatibility-in-c) and I'm aware of the struct encapsulation hack, but that's **not** what I want. I have a pile of code and I want to check it for this particular type of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

What about [splint](http://www.splint.org/)? (I have not checked whether it can do what you want. I doubt it will though.)

Or alternatively, what about using C99's `stdbool.h` and `bool` type?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)

I've already looked on splint. This is actually the first tool I checked. I ran it in -strict mode on my example and from it's point of view everything was clean.. Additionally, I looked through it's manual and checked every flag in 'Types' section but I wasn't able to find anything useful to me.

Regarding the bool, it's just the example from that $$$ windoze PC-lint manual. The actual code deals with ints and longs, no bools.

Answer (score 0):

"lint" was originally a unix tool - is it no longer included in standard distros?

If not,  `gcc -wall` supposedly gives most of the same warnings.

Comment: No, the equivalent tool is "splint". Splint can't do C99, and see wilx's answer and comments for that.