# Preventing automatic casts with integers

Tags: c++, c, audio, casting, typedef

I'm developing an audio application (in C++) and I have lots of functions that call each other that either take the number of frames (i.e. 1 mono or 2 stereo float samples) or the raw number of samples...

It is getting harder to keep track of the semantics of each function (samples or frames?) and when to mult or div by nChannels, so I would like to somehow do a typedef samples_t and frames_t (to unsigned int) and have the compiler help me out...

Is there any simple way to have an implicit conversion from frames_t to samples_t be marked as an error in C++?

Comment: For C++, you may find this useful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_units/Quick_Start.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enforce strong type checking in C (type strictness for typedefs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs) or [Is there a good way to force type incompatibility in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140035/is-there-a-good-way-to-force-type-incompatibility-in-c).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You can use «release» in place of Boost version that always takes you to documentation for the latest stable release (recommended way to go)

Comment: Also being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140035/is-there-a-good-way-to-force-type-incompatibility-in-c

Comment: As a developer who writes this kind of code for a living and has never had this problem, I would venture to suggest that perhaps you are asking the wrong question/going about this the wrong way. Other options are to standardize on frames OR samples, rather than using one sometimes and the other at other times, or use a datastructure that carries the raw sample data and the number of samples and frames for your sampled data and pass that structure around.

Comment: In cases when integer can have a limited number of values the enumerations is a choice, but I guess it is out of the question in this case ...

Comment: This won't help with a compiler-enforced way of distinguishing types, but it is worth reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Bjorn Roche: Indeed, that is the very best approach... if i was starting from scratch :) The reason I wanted a low friction option is because, already with 10000's of code lines written across some years,  its starting to get messy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless frames_t and samples_t are actually different types.  You could make them POD structs containing an integer, but typedefing them will have no effect.

Comment: Whole Value idiom, right? http://martin-moene.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/light-on-whole-value.html

Comment: Not the most beautiful solution, but it actually worked decently enough... Now I can at least protect the most sensitive code (where the processing stack switches from one to the other) and I managed to catch most of the annoying bugs (that are hard to track down because they manifest themselves by playing sound and half or twice the speed it should)

Answer (score 2):

You could go all out and define your own system within [boost.units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_units/Quick_Start.html), or alternatively just use the [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) macro to create a strong typedef for each type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `typedef` but boost can help you out.

If all you want is non-convertible types, `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` will do the trick: It will allow you to make up multiple types that are all `unsigned` but not convertible between each other when being passed around.

But in your particular application you may wish to consider the boost units framework where you can actually create units types, where the results from arithmetic inherit the proper units (so for example `freq * time` yields unitless).