# Any performance penalty for wrapping int in a class?

Tags: c++

I have a project with many vectors, sets and maps. In most cases the key/index is an integer. I am considering creating small classes like:

```
class PhoneRepoIx //index into map {phone_number => pointer}
{
public:
  int n;
};

class PersonIx //index into map {social_security_number => pointer}
{
public:
  int n;
};
```

Would I incur any speed or memory penalty? With memory I am 90% sure that there would be no memory cost per instance, only per class-type. With speed I am not clear.

**Motivation:**
With the above approach, the compiler would do some extra type-checking for me. Also, with well chosen explicit type-names, the reader of my code will see more easily what I am doing. As of now I am using int everywhere and I chose the variable names to express what each index is. With the above, my variable names could be shorter.

Note:
Tyepdefs do not address my issue completely as the compiler would not do any extra type-checking, internally all the types would just be int.

Comment: Writing `struct PersonIx { int n; }` is shorter, precisely the same, and also no need for any typedefs. And I also think there would be no overhead whatsoever (except where the code using the type will be artificially made less than optimal because of the wrapper)

Comment: I don't see how `struct PersonIx { int n; }` is shorter than `typedef int PersonIx`.  Also, with the existing types you can handle operations on the index (if that's necessary), which you would need to override for your specific types.  Also, if it's truly an index, you may not want it to be signed (so, use `size_t`).  That said, I don't think the question was worthy of a down vote.

Comment: `Tyepdefs do not address my issue completely as the compiler would not do any extra type-checking, internally all the types would just be int.` What does this even mean? What "extra type checking" do you think you need? We're going to need to use a usage example here.

Comment: @Falmarri, if you use typedefs then PhoneRepoIx and PersonIx are the same, but if you use classes or structs then they are not. The OP wants to get that extra typechecking from the compiler.

Comment: @Falmarri: "Your last order was 5 too much."  Does "5" mean a quantity, package weight, a payment amount, a payment date?

Comment: @Chad: Those are't the same thing. In the latter, `PersonIx` is interchangeable with `int`, while in the former it is a new type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enforce strong type checking in C (type strictness for typedefs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs)

Comment: @GManNickG: He could use a `enum` in C++11 that doesn't auto-decay into `int`.

Comment: Ignore the naysayers, they are clueless. This is a good approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don’t think it’s a duplicate, for three reasons: 1) even though some of the answers there are good, the accepted answer to the other question sucks. 2) This question is asking specifically after performance implications. 3) the “duplicate” is actually about C (which explains the accepted answer).

Comment: I can just add that having structs like these is adviced by the Book effective c++. You can also connect additional information such as type name using traits.

Comment: @Konrad: Yeah, I repented of the close vote tool late.  Still a closely related question, which all interested parties should scrutinize, even if it doesn't answer the perf question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different compilers have different optimization abilities and different bugs. It is theoretically possible to compile this with precisely zero overhead. Will your compiler attain this theoretical limit? The answer is a definite "maybe". At least some compilers are known to do it at least some of the time.

The more interesting question is whether you should be worried over a possible performance degradation. And the answer to this question is a strong "no". Not until your program does in fact show unacceptable performance figures.

Comment: This answer vastly understates the ability of modern compilers. I’d *expect* a decent compiler to compile this code down to zero overhead. In fact, there are several libraries out there (among them parts of the C++ standard library) which *require* compilers to do this, lest they suffer massive performance blows. In general, the answer is not a “maybe”, it’s either a “yes” or a “change your compiler”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I have on several occasions compared assembly generated by g++ for naked and wrapped types. Most of the time there was zero overhead, but not always. clang++ is somewhat worse than g++ in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the use of templates to get what you want.

```
template <typename T>
struct Index {
    Index(int value) : value(value) {}
    int value;
};
```

This is used like.

```
struct PhoneRepoIx {};
Index<PhoneRepoIx> PhoneIndex(1);
list[PhoneIndex.value];
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two functions which will commonly be called on this class:

- Constructor
- operator< (since STL map is a tree impl, the keys should support this)

I think the above answer "don't worry" sounds pretty good (profile then optimize).  But to take a crack at why this won't cause any slowdown (guesswork):

- Constructor: No reason why a decent compiler couldn't turn this into a stack pointer increment (to make space for the int) followed by setting the available space.
- operator<: No reason why a decent compiler couldn't inline the simple comparison between the 'n's of the two objects.