# How to generate two proxy classes using the same interface in swig

Tags: java, c++, swig, typedef, proxy-classes

I have some code like below:

```
class SingleValue
{
public:
   SingleValue()
   {}

   ~SingleValue()
   {}

   const std::string& getValue()const
   {
    return m_nSingleValue;
   }
private:
   int m_nSingleValue;
};

typedef SingleValue RoadType;
typedef SingleValue RoadSubType;
typedef SingleValue FunctionalClass;
```

now I want to use SWIG to generate a Java wrapper, But it generate only one proxy class 'SingleValue', I want to know how generate the other proxy class using swig, but I can't find some relative information after googling.

I try %rename, but it only generate one proxy class, not three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve seems to be strong typing. SWIG by default tries to expose an interface with the same behaviours as you would see in C++, so in that case the behaviour is expected - weak typedefs are all C++ offers. You can work around this though.

Given the header file:

```
#include <string>

class SingleValue
{
public:
   SingleValue()
   {}

   ~SingleValue()
   {}

   std::string getValue() const
   {
      return std::to_string(m_nSingleValue);
   }
private:
   int m_nSingleValue;
};

typedef SingleValue RoadType;
typedef SingleValue RoadSubType;
typedef SingleValue FunctionalClass;

inline RoadType make_road() { return RoadType(); }
FunctionalClass make_func() { return FunctionalClass(); }
```

which differs from yours only in the corrections to `getValue()` and the addition of two inline functions for testing we can wrap it and get close to strong typedef semantics by doing:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>

class SingleValue
{
public:
   SingleValue();
   ~SingleValue();
   std::string getValue() const;
};

struct RoadType : public SingleValue {
};

struct RoadSubType : public SingleValue {
};

struct FunctionalClass : public SingleValue {
};

RoadType make_road();
FunctionalClass make_func();
```

Notice that I've not shown SWIG the typedef at all and I've lied completely about the type and existance of `RoadType` etc., but this is OK like that because all the code that gets generated by SWIG is legal and correct still.

This cause an interface to be generated where the `make_X` functions return distinct types.

---

If you wanted to avoid the duplication between the header file and the interface file you could introduce a macro to help, the header file becomes:

```
#include <string>

class SingleValue
{
public:
   SingleValue()
   {}

   ~SingleValue()
   {}

   std::string getValue() const
   {
      return std::to_string(m_nSingleValue);
   }
private:
   int m_nSingleValue;
};

#ifndef STRONG_TYPEDEF
#define STRONG_TYPEDEF(o,n) typedef o n
#endif

STRONG_TYPEDEF(SingleValue, RoadType);
STRONG_TYPEDEF(SingleValue, RoadSubType);
STRONG_TYPEDEF(SingleValue, FunctionalClass);

inline RoadType make_road() { return RoadType(); }
FunctionalClass make_func() { return FunctionalClass(); }
```

Which means the interface file can simply become:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <std_string.i>

#define STRONG_TYPEDEF(o, n) struct n : o {};

%include "test.h"
```

This works partly because `SingleValue` is a class so the strong typedef can become a sub-class in the Java type system for it to enforce checking on. If the type isn't a class you can still do the same thing without using inheritance, for example [the first part of an answer I gave on a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11602306/168175) using D would work - you'd want to elaborate on the empty structs though if there isn't any inheritance in play.