# compiler warning for cast missing on typedef variables

Tags: c, gcc

I can't find a way of doing this, but is there a compiler flag for GCC/LLVM where I can get it to warn me about this:

```
typedef float distance_feet_t;
typedef float distance_meters_t;

void shouldWarnMe ( void )
{
    distance_feet_t feet = 10.0f;
    distance_meters_t meters = 20.0f;

    /* this should generate a warning */
    distance_meters_t total = meters + feet;
}
```

In essence I want to redefine the variable types such that if I start mixing them then the compiler would warn that I am missing a cast.

I've tried -Wall: no warning.

There are ways of solving this problem without using typedefs. However the question is, is there a way of doing it with typedefs as described?

Comment: Put simply, nope: typedefs are just a level above macros, and are merely aliases to existing types.

Comment: Also FWIW, in C++ with Boost and for the particular example given, the problem has been handled by [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931720/warn-if-another-typedefd-name-of-a-type-is-used-in-an-argument-list may help you (there is a reference to sparse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `distance_feet_t` and `distance_meters_t` are the exact same type.  I don't know of any way to do this in pure C, but you could definitely do it in C++ by defining a class for each different unit type and defining the appropriate overloaded operators (though there's a lot of annoying boilerplate there).

Side note: identifiers at global scope ending with the suffix `_t` are considered to be reserved by the POSIX standard; I'd suggest avoiding using such identifiers, although the likelihood of a conflict is pretty low (and easy to fix, should it happen).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "clean" way, but there are some tricks.

[Enforce strong type checking in C (type strictness for typedefs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs)

I usually go with the `struct` trick, if I *really* have to do it, otherwise I just use lint.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` does not create a new type but creates an alias for an existing type.

It means:

```
typedef float distance_feet_t;
typedef float distance_meters_t;
```

`float`, `distance_feet_t` and `distance_meters_t`are different names for the exact the same type.