# Warn if another typedef'd name of a type is used in an argument list

Tags: c, gcc

Consider a large project, where many types are `typedef`'d, e.g.

```
typedef int age;
typedef int height;
```

and some functions getting arguments of those types:

```
void printPerson(age a, height h) {
    printf("Age %d, Height %d\n", a, h);
}
```

Is there a way to warn at compile time, if those arguments are of the wrong type, e.g.

```
age a = 30;
height h = 180;
printPerson(h, a); /* No warning, because a and h are both integers */
```

Does gcc (or some static code analysis tool) have an option to warn in such cases?

Comment: I don't think there could be a warning because both types are compatible. I think your example is oversimplified, since it's not clear why would someone try that!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4669454/694576

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/q/376452/3235496

Comment: Whoever typedef'd int to age and height should have keyboard privileges revoked.  Im very sorry you have to deal with this.

Comment: @qexyn: that's just an example. But wait... What's the Problem with it?

Comment: Might as well start programming in Ada! There seems little point in bringing in only one aspect of that sort of language and leaving out the rest. I would argue in favour of leaving that aspect of C/C++ as is. Use a language that already has features like that instead of importing them into another language.

Comment: If you would have such a strong typing, your initialization with `int` constants would be illegal, too.

Comment: @urzeit It is a confusion between type and instance.  Height is an instance of int just like just like Initialized is an instance of bool.  If you typedef type names into instance names, you introduce confusion.  My sympathy is given because it sounds like you are dealing with a large project full of this.

Comment: @NicholasSmith what's wrong with not wanting to compare your age to your shoe size? They're both numbers, sure, but that's the only similarity, so obviously they should not be assignment-compatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this in GCC.

There is [a feature request](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59851) to add this, based on the Sparse `nocast` attribute.  However, this hasn't been implemented.  If you can use Sparse, though, you could do this by marking each typedef with `__attribute__((nocast))`.

In C++ you can do this by making wrapper classes rather than typedefs, and then simply not defining implicit conversions for them.

Comment: At least per the test cases attached to the feature request you link in your answer, the scenario as per the OP would not be detected.

Comment: Dang, right you are, I had forgotten that.  `bitwise` might help a bit more but it has other implications.  It seems like a new attribute is needed.

Answer (score 2):

[Klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com) has some checks related to what they call "strong typing".

For your code it throws STRONG.TYPE.ASSIGN.ARG because argument types do not match.

It also complains about assigning `int` values (the consts) to `age` and `height` typed variables and about using the variables as `int` in `printf`.

I heard it is quite expensive, though.

Answer (score 2):

As has been made clear by the other responses, you're not going to get this for free from gcc.  You are definitely into the world of static analysis tools to solve this.

There have been several suggestions for this, some of which require extra annotation, some of which don't but may be more than you're looking for.  I therefore thought I'd throw one more into the mix...

A long stand by for me has been the various command line lint tools.  In your case, I think PC-lint/flexelint fits very well even though it is a commercial tool.  See [here](http://www.gimpel.com/html/strong.htm) for its strong type checking.

Answer (score 0):

No, there cannot be.  A compiler will warn you if you're doing (or about to do) something *illegal*. It is not supposed to know (or determine the correctness of) the *values* which you will be passing as function parameter. As long as the types are same, it does not have any reason to complain.

However, in case of *type* mismatch, it will alert you.

Comment: @urzeit but the thing I'm trying to tell is that it does not work on _values_.

Comment: Well, but it might know, "Hey, h is of type height, but in the argument list, it should be a, the programmer might have made a mistake" and print out a warning (which has to be checked by the programmer, of course). The tool might do that by only lexing the code and not doing anything with values.

Comment: This just not true, e.g. gcc warns if you do `if (foo = bar)` although it is perfectly legal. Warnings are usually thrown when a code analyzer "thinks" something is not as intended. And this is exactly what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Error will be generated only when types are different. can you wrap these types inside struct and use macros to automate definition and assignment.

If you are willing to use enum instead of integers then there is an option for warnings on use of mixed enums in static code analysis tool named coverity.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CoverityCheckerDictionary
look for  MIXED_ENUMS.

Comment: That's not what I asked. In my case it is not possible to change the types, because the functions called are external libraries.

Comment: You did not mentioned that in your question.  coverity may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated, there is no support for this in C. If you absolutely want strong type checking to happen, you could do like this:

```
typedef struct {int a;} age;
typedef struct {int h;} height;

void printPerson(age a, height h)
{
    printf("Age %d, height %d\n", a.a, h.h);
}

age a = {30};
height h = {180};

printPerson(h, a);  // will generate errors
```

Beware that this might have some performance impact, though.

Comment: That way I had to change much code from `a` to `a.a`, so this is not an option. Thanks anyway. As I wrote in Pointer's anwer, I can not change all types, because some of them are calls to external library functions.