# Comparing Types Of Names In C

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to write a macro in C (alas, not C++) in a way to trap certain errors, in particular if I pass a name of the wrong type.

For example, with

```
typedef int APLNELM;
typedef int APLRANK;
#define IsScalar(a) ((a) == 0)

APLNELM AplNelm = 0;
APLRANK AplRank = 0;
```

Calling `IsScalar (AplRank)` is correct because Scalar is a Rank concept, but `IsScalar (AplNelm)` is wrong because Scalar is not a # elements concept.

Can some clever person find a way to write the `IsScalar` macro such that it checks the type of the name passed to it to ensure that it is of type `APLRANK`?  Feel free to rewrite the original example in any equivalent way if that provides a solution.

Comment: Typedef declarations do not make types. `APLNELM` and `APLRANK` are the exact same type, and both are exactly the same as `int`.

Comment: Does `IsScalar` have to be a macro? You could create structs to represent your different types and make `IsScalar` an actual function that accepts the proper datatype.

Comment: Are you expecting a runtime test or a compilation error?

Comment: I think @Ranic a very appropriated solution. If you still care about type size you can remove extra padding from your struct and make it match to exact `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376452/enforce-strong-type-checking-in-c-type-strictness-for-typedefs . Please have a look; there's a lot of nice answers there!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define two integer types that are different, the straight `typedef` approach fails, because `typedef` creates synonyms for the same type, never creates new types.

There is a manner to create different integer types, but even in this case, there is no way to "detect" them through their values.

For example, observe this code:

```
 enum myint1_e {min1 = -32767, max1 = 32767};
 enum myint2_e {min2 = -32767, max2 = 32767};
 typedef enum myint1_e integer1_t;
 typedef enum myint2_e integer2_t;

 integer1_t x1 = 0;
 integer2_t x2 = 0;
```

Now, the two types `enum myint1_t` and `enum myint2_t` are different integer types.
See C11: 6.7.2.3.(par.5):

> Two declarations of [...] enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types.

So, their `typedef`-ed versions are, too, different.
Thus, the variables `x1` and `x2` have different types.
The integer value 0 can be assigned to both variables.

Now, if you want to check that the type of a variable is the one that you want, you can try doing that:

```
 #define VERIFY_INT1TYPE(a) ((integer1_t*)(0) == (&a))
```

But this method only offers a Warning message, and not the "comparisson with value false" that you expected.

Explanation: Although the integer types are, in some way, interchangeable in assignment operations, on the other hand their "pointer to" versions are always different types. Thus, a sentence like `x1 == x2` has not any problem at all, **but the comparisson of a value of two different pointer types will raise a warning message**.

**Remark:**  The expression `(integer1_t*)(0)` is the NULL pointer cast to type `integer1_t*`.

**Example:**

```
  VERIFY_INT1TYPE(x2);
```

This example raise a warning message when I compiled with GCC.

Comment: I like this solution, but I can't get it to work.  That is, I tried
    void main (void)
    {
        enum myint1_e {min1 = -32767, max1 = 32767};
        enum myint2_e {min2 = -32767, max2 = 32767};
        typedef enum myint1_e integer1_t;
        typedef enum myint2_e integer2_t;

        integer1_t x1 = 0;
        integer2_t x2 = 0;

        #define VERIFY_INT1TYPE(a) ((integer1_t*)(&(a)))

        VERIFY_INT1TYPE (x1);
        VERIFY_INT1TYPE (x2);
    } // End main

which compiled (using MSVC 11.0) without error with cl -c -Wall foo.c

Comment: So sorry about the formatting mess.  I guess I need help with that, too!

Comment: @BobSmith: My original definition didn't work. So I changed it to something more easy to understand, and that it is working for me. Please, check the new definition of the macro that I wrote.

Comment: I like this solution, but I can't get it to work.  That is, I tried your code with `VERIFY_INT1TYPE (x1)` and with `(x2)` and neither generated an error (using MSVC 11.0 with `cl -c -Wall foo.c`).  I also tried assigning the results into `integer1_t *y1;` and `integer2_t *y2;` also compiled without error.

Comment: @BobSmith: Have you tried the modified version of the macro?

Comment: Sadly, MSVC 11.0 doesn't complain about your new code.  I greatly appreciate your help and thought we had a solution, but MSVC appears to be much more forgiving than GCC.

Comment: @BobSmith: Take a look to `_Generic` (generic selections). It could help (needs a compiler compatible with C11 standard): [Generic Selections](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56446/discussion-between-bob-smith-and-pablo1977).

Comment: MS has accepted this as a bug -- see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/908806/enum-ptrs-not-different for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only two types that will ever be passed into the `isScalar` macro, then you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct APLNELM {
    int nelm;
    char a[1];
};

struct APLRANK {
    int rank;
    char a[2];
};

#define isScalar(b) (sizeof b.a == 2)

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    struct APLNELM temp1;
    struct APLRANK temp2;

    printf("%d\n", isScalar(temp1));
    printf("%d\n", isScalar(temp2));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
0
1
```

Comment: Or, a compile-time error:  `int only_in_APLRANK` and then `#define isScalar(b) b.only_in_APLRANK` it will give a compiler erro if other struct without a member called `only_in_APLRANK` is used in `isScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but I highly suggest you don't use it as it wouldn't be super maintainable:

```
typedef int APLNELM;
typedef int APLRANK;

typedef unsigned int TYPETRAITS;

#define TRAIT_SCALAR 0x1
#define TYPETRAITS_APLNELM TRAIT_SCALAR /*whatever else you want, up to 32 traits*/
#define TYPETRAITS_APLRANK 0/*whatever else you want, up to 32 traits*/

#define GET_TYPE_TRAITS(X) TYPETRAITS_##X

#define IS_SCALAR(X) (X & TRAIT_SCALAR)

#define IS_TYPE_SCALAR(X) IS_SCALAR(GET_TYPE_TRAITS(X))

int main()
{
   const int aplnelm_traints = GET_TYPE_TRAITS(APLNELM);
   const int aplrang_traints = GET_TYPE_TRAITS(APLRANK);

   const bool is_aplnelm_scalar = IS_TYPE_SCALAR(APLNELM);
   const bool is_aplrang_scalar = IS_TYPE_SCALAR(APLNELM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gived up with following code (requires GNU extensions: [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) and [Statement Exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int APLNELM;
typedef int APLRANK;

#define IsScalar(a) \
    ({ \
        /* Override typedefs in block scope */ \
        typedef char APLNELM; \
        typedef int  APLRANK; \
        /* Create variable with typeof(a) type; \
         * then compare it by sizeof with APLNELM */ \
        typeof(a) b; sizeof b == sizeof(APLNELM); \
    })

int main(void)
{
    APLNELM a = 5;
    APLRANK b = 5;

    printf("IsScalar: %d\n", IsScalar(a) ? 1 : 0);
    printf("IsScalar: %d\n", IsScalar(b) ? 1 : 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that `typeof(a)` is actually not replaced by `APLNELM` or `APLRANK`. C is not dynamic language, I agree that `struct` concept would be better suited for such differentiation.

Comment: If you're going to use GNU-extensions maybe `typeof()` might be useful. You can compare types, IIRC.

Comment: IMHO you can only compare them by `sizeof` operator. `typeof` is more like "replace me with my type". The is no way to get actual type's name (which apparently would be `int` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to wrap the integer in a one-field struct, to enforce strong typing. To avoid the final production code being suboptimal, compile twice with different macro definitions; once with structs to detect errors, once without structs for optimal code.

```
#ifdef STRONG_TYPING

#define TYPE(basetype, field)      struct { basetype field; }
#define INITIALIZER(value)         {(value)}
#define AS_BASETYPE(field, value)  ((value).field)

#else

#define TYPE(basetype, field)      basetype
#define INITIALIZER(value)         (value)
#define AS_BASETYPE(field, value)  (value)

#endif

typedef TYPE(int, alpnelm) APLNELM;
typedef TYPE(int, alprank) APLRANK;

#define IsScalar(a) (AS_BASETYPE(aplrank, a) == 0)
```

With `STRONG_TYPING` defined, `IsScalar(SomeAplNelm)` will give a compiler error. Without `STRONG_TYPING`, the overhead of structs will be completely gone. Naturally, all modules must to be compiled with the same definition before linking, or your executable is likely to crash.

In your program code, you will have to apply some discipline when it comes to using the macros. Declaration example:

```
APLNELM MyAplNelm1;
APLNELM MyAplNelm2 = INITIALIZER(0);
```

Assignment:

```
AS_BASETYPE(aplnelm, MyAplNelm1) = 0;
AS_BASETYPE(aplnelm, MyAplNelm2) = AS_BASETYPE(aplnelm, MyAplNelm1);
```

It is still allowed to exchange values between different 'strong' types; as long as you specify the correct type (name of the field in the struct) for each individual value.

```
AS_BASETYPE(aplnelm, MyAplNelm2) = AS_BASETYPE(aplrank, MyAplRank);
```

Please note you always need `AS_BASETYPE` to access a variable of one of the 'strong' types. This will make the code more verbose (please feel free to choose a shorter name for the macro), but there's nothing wrong with that. It's just a notion of metadata you are adding; it should actually improve maintainability.