# C compiler checking of a typedef'ed void *

Tags: c, typedef, void

We have an anonymous type, `typedef`ed to `void *`, which is the handle for an API (all code in C11).  It is deliberately `void *` as what it is pointing to changes depending on the platform we are compiled for and we also don't want the application to try dereferencing it.  Internally we know what it should be pointing to and we cast it appropriately.  This is fine, the code is public, we've been using it for years, it cannot be changed.

The problem is that we now need to introduce another one of these, and we don't want the user to get the two confused, we want the compiler to throw an error if the wrong handle is passed to one of our functions.  However, all of the versions of all of the C compilers I have tried so far (GCC, Clang, MSVC) don't care; they know that the underlying type is `void *` and so anything goes (this is with `-Wall` and `-Werror`).  Putting it another way, our `typedef` has not achieved anything, we might as well have just used `void *`.  I have also tried Lint and [CodeChecker](https://codechecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), who also don't seem to care (though you could probably question my configurations for these).  Note that I am not able to use `-Wpedantic` as we include third party code where that wouldn't fly.

I have tried making the new thing a specific `typedef`ed pointer rather than a `void *` but that doesn't entirely fix things as the compiler is still happy for the caller to pass that new specific `typedef`ed pointer into the existing functions that are expecting the existing handle `typedef`.

Is there (a) a way to construct a new anonymous handle such that the compiler will not allow it to be passed to the existing functions or (b) a checker that we can apply to pick the problem up, at least in our own use of these APIs?

Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int contents;
} existingThing_t;
typedef void *anonExistingHandle_t;


typedef struct {
    char contents[10];
} newThing_t;
typedef void *anonNewHandle_t;
typedef newThing_t *newHandle_t;


static void functionExisting(anonExistingHandle_t handle)
{
    existingThing_t *pThing = (existingThing_t *) handle;
    
    // Perform the function
    (void) pThing;
}

static void functionNew(anonNewHandle_t handle)
{
    newThing_t *pThing = (newThing_t *) handle;
    
    // Perform a new function
    (void) pThing;
}

int main() {
    anonExistingHandle_t existingHandle = NULL;
    anonNewHandle_t newHandleA = NULL;
    newHandle_t newHandleB = NULL;

    functionExisting(existingHandle);
    functionNew(newHandleA);

    // These should result in a compilation error
    functionExisting(newHandleA);
    functionNew(existingHandle);
    functionExisting(newHandleB);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you want is called "strong typedef". Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/376452/12122460) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there (a) a way to construct a new anonymous handle such that the compiler will not allow it to be passed to the existing functions

Yes, use a type that can't be implicitly converted to `void *`. Use a structure.

```
typedef struct {
    struct newThing_s *p;
} anonNewHandle_t;
```

---

Anyway, your design is just flawed and disables all static compiler checks. Do not use `void *`, instead use structures or structures with `void *` inside, to enable compile checks. Research how the very, very standard `FILE *` works. `FILE` is not `void`.

Do not use typedef pointers. They are *very* confusing. https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL05-C.+Use+typedefs+of+non-pointer+types+only

I suggest rewriting your library so that you do not use `void *` and do not use typedef pointers.

The design, *may* look like the following:

```
// handle.h
struct handle_s;
typedef struct {
  struct handle_s *p;
} handle_t;
handle_t handle_init(void);
void handle_deinit(handle_t t);
void handle_do_something(handle_t t);

// handle.c
struct handle_s {
   int the_stuff_you_need;
};
handle_t handle_init(void) {
   return (handle_t){
        .p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct handle_s))
   };
}
void handle_do_something(handle_t h) {
     struct hadnle_s *t = h->p;
     // etc.
}

// anotherhandle.h
   // similar to above
typedef struct {
   struct anotherhandle_s *p;
} anotherhandle_t;
void anotherhandle_do_something(anotherhandle_t h);

// main
int main() {
   handle_t h = handle_new();
   handle_do_something(h);
   handle_free(h);

   anotherhandle_do_something(h); // compiler error
}
```

Comment: All good advice, can't disagree, aside from the "suggest you rewrite" part: the existing `typedef void *` is out there and has been in use in customer code for years; it is part of a porting layer that customers will have written their own ports for, changing it would break their world. Ergo it seems there is actually no true defence. So much for `typedef` in C, must admit I thought it was _always_ strong, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: ? `typedef` was never strong, it's just an alias. It's like `#define`. `why wouldn't it be?` https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.8p3 `A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified`

Comment: I live and learn.